# Precision Regarding Proposition 1.15 in Folland's Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, compactness

**1.15 Proposition.**(page 33) Let $F:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be increasing and right continuous. If $(a_j,b_j]$ $(j=1,\dots,n)$ are disjoint $h-$intervals, let

$$\mu_0\bigg(\bigcup_{j=1}^n (a_j,b_j] \bigg)=\sum_{j=1}^n [ F(b_j)-F(a_j)]$$

and let $\mu_0(\emptyset)=0$. Then $\mu_0$ is a premeasure on the algebra $\mathcal{A}$.

Note: the algebra $\mathcal{A}$ is the the collection of finite disjoint unions of $h-$intervals, defined to be any set of the form $(a,b]$ or $(a,\infty)$ or $\emptyset$, where $-\infty\leq a<b<\infty$.

At the end of the proof of Proposition 1.15 on page 34, Folland uses a compactness argument to show that $\mu_0$ is countably additive in the case of an interval $I=(a,b]$ where both $a$ and $b$ are finite. He then mentions that the same reasoning can be applied when  $a=-\infty$ or to $b=\infty$ to get

(i) $F(b)-F(-M)\leq\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\mu_0(I_j)+2\epsilon$

(ii) $F(M)-F(a)\leq\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\mu_0(I_j)+2\epsilon$

respectively, where $0<M<\infty$ is arbitrary. I have three questions:

1. In the case $a=-\infty$  I think that we actually have $F(b)-F(-M)\leq\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\mu_0(I_j)+\epsilon$ since in that case we don't have to find a $\delta<0$ such that $F(a+\delta)-F(a)<\epsilon$. Am I correct?
2. In the case $b=\infty$  we might have $b_j=\infty$ for some $j$. In that case do we define $\delta_j=0$ and proceed with the same argument?
3. What about the case where both $a=-\infty$ and $b=\infty$ ? Is there a reason why Folland doesn't mention this case?

Thanks a lot for your help. My goal is to redo the proof as in the book in each of the 3 cases.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could write the statement of Proposition 1.15.

Comment: @Izralbu Ok I just added the statement.